# swift segue to view controller from file not view controller

Tags: ios, swift, function, view, uiviewcontroller

I am creating a segue to another vie controller, however the file I want to send it in is linked, but is not the current view controller.

I tried the following code:

```
self.showNextController(FinishViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But I got the error argument passed to cal takes no arguments.

Comment: Can you please post the exact error message & the signature of `showNextController`?

Comment: I am new to swift, what is the signature. The exact error message is "argument passed to call takes no arguments"

Comment: The signature is the function's declaration -- not the code, just the name and arguments.